# how to create a 30 minutes timeslot.. Im getting the start date and end date from backend

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<WorkingHourModel> workingHours = response['hours'];
    int startTime = int.parse(workingHours[0].startTime.split(':')[0]);
    int endTime = int.parse(workingHours[0].endTime.split(':')[0]);
    int hoursLeft = endTime - startTime + 1;
    List<String> hours =
        List.generate(hoursLeft, (i) => '${(endTime - i)}:00').reversed
            .toList();
          
    print('Hours-------- $hours');
    return {
      'success': true,
      'hours': hours,
    };
  }
```

//this will give the time slots as '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00'
//Start time will be 1:00 and end time will be 4:00.

### Heading

But i need 30 mins breakage, like,
'1:00', '1:30', '2:00', '2:30', '3:00', '3:30', '4:00'

Kindly help..

Answer (score 0):

This should generate the list as you want it:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
     // lets assume 9 to 5
     int startTime = 9;
     int endTime = 17;
     int hoursLeft = endTime - startTime + 1;

    final hours = List.generate(hoursLeft * 2, (i) => '${endTime - (i/2).truncate()}:${i%2 == 1 ? '00' : '30'}').reversed.toList();
          
    print('Hours-------- $hours');
}
```

> Hours-------- [9:00, 9:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30]

Generally speaking, if you have more complicated calculations (what happens if someone works 18:00 to 05:00 in the nightshift?) you may want to use the proper datatypes instead of integers and string concatenation.

Comment: Sorry but there is a issue here..                                                                               
this is out from by adding the above line of code..                                             
Hours-------- [2:00, 2:30, 3:00, 3:30, 4:00, 4:30, 5:00, 5:30, 6:00, 6:30].... The actual output is [2:00, 2:30, 3:00, 3:30, 4:00, 4:30, 5:00, 5:30, 6:00] everytime the end time with 30 mins is added..

Comment: If it's one too many, just subtract one from `hoursLeft * 2`, making it `(hoursLeft * 2)-1`

Comment: Not working.. its adding 30 to the hour which has :00, like if it is 4:00 - taking 4:30 for all the time.

Comment: {"start_time":"09:00","end_time":"17:00"} => This is the response.                                     the output is [9:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30]..                                                                                                                            The output should be : [9:00, 9:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00]